# TouchesMoved With 2 Fingers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to make a simple landscape "split screen" app where two players can play at once (each player gets one half of the screen), but I am having trouble tracking both touches at the same time. This is the code I am trying to use:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
         CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
         if (point.x < 240) {
             [player1 updatePoint:point];
         } else {
             [player2 updatePoint:point];
         }
     }
 }
```

But I am obviously doing something wrong. Although this code works fine, it will only track one finger and move the player on the side of the screen the finger is on. What is my code lacking? Is this task more difficult to pull off then I think it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set UIView's [multipleTouchEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/multipleTouchEnabled) to YES?

Answer (score 0):

`multipleTouchEnabled` should be set to YES for the UIView.